# I cannot for the life of me get my world image to render in the window clearly

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]No matter what I do or try I cannot get any image that I place in my world image to render clearly or in the window.  I need to render a tree in the window.  As recommended I have been using high resolution images none of which are working.[image]

Comment: Has the window a glass shader (transmission) or is it transparent? From polyhaven.com you can get HDRIs and also 8k low dynamic preview JPGs. Press the hamburger menu (3 lines) and look for the tone-mapped JPG. They are between 12MB and 56MB big but much smaller than the 8k HDRI. This way you can use your shader setup with a 1k HDIR for the light and an 8k preview JPG for the tree image which is not blurry.

Answer (score 0):

If the camera is static and doesn't move you can use just a plane with an image of a tree. If the camera moves a cylinder would be better to keep the illusion.

The usage of two environment images (HDIRs), one for the lighting and one for the background image, should work, too. But if your windows have *Transmission* enabled then you need to change the *Light Path* node connection if you want to bake the indirect lighting for Eevee.

Here is an example with the plane that has a [picture of a tree](https://www.housebeautiful.com/lifestyle/gardening/g31228292/fast-growing-shade-plants/). It's placed in front of the window.
[image: scene screenshot]

The shader for the windows can be fully transparent or transmissive or a mix of both. Transmission makes the background in Eevee always a bit blurry (Blender 2.93.5). I'm not sure why.

If you want a realistic render when consider making the background outside of the window overexposed and much brighter than the room. Also, keep in mind that a real camera has a depth of focus. That is, the background is usually blurred when an object in the foreground is in focus.

Of course, if you want to have it in a more stylized/artistic way you can have it "darker" (=not brighter) and clear.

[image: example render]
Using *Emission Strength* 4 for the background image here. The glass is fully transparent (alpha value=0). *Blend Mode* for the material is *Alpha Hashed*, *Shadow Mode* is *Node*. This means, there is no visible glass at all ;-)

To fake the sunlight there is a small (20cm x 20cm) area light outside with 40000W. The *Light Probe > Irradiance Volume* is baked without this area light to create the sunshine and shadows.

(The size of the Irradiance Volume was messed up on the first screenshot).